# Drupal 8 PDO Prepared Statements bindValue error

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, pdo

I am having trouble with this query. This query results in the following error.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE table SET user_id = :uid";
if ($con = $connection->prepare($sql)) {
  $con->bindValue(':uid', intval($this->uid), PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $con->debugDumpParams();
  $con->execute();
}
```

Parameters

```
Params:  1
Key: Name: [4] :uid
paramno=-1
name=[4] ":uid"
is_param=1
param_type=1
```

Query That works.

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE table SET user_id = :uid";
if ($con = $connection->prepare($sql)) {
    $con->execute([':uid' => intval($this->uid)]);
}
```

**Question** Why can't I bind any parameter or value to the PDO prepared statement?

I am using Drupal 8 and I believe that their connections replace the PDO default driver.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: I recommend passing the parameters in the `execute` unless you are using `blobs`. It works very reliably.

Comment: @RyanVincent It may have something to do with Drupal's custom drivers. I've altered this query in several different ways. Is there a way to debug the PDO statement and get the driver configuration?

Comment: @RyanVincent here is the drupal documentation for PDO custom driver https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!Statement.php/class/Statement/8 it looks like they don't implement bindValue or bindParam. That could lead to the error I see. I'm going to look into Drupal configeration and figure out how I can use the default driver rather than the custom Drupal driver.

Comment: @RyanVincent The same error occurs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102919/discussion-between-neoaptt-and-ryan-vincent).

Comment: First good question in PDO tag in months.

Comment: BTW, you should accept your answer as it will make this post more relevant for google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 8 replaces the default PDO driver with a custom driver that Drupal uses to insert, update, prepare statements, ect... These drivers override the default operations. So if you want a complete customize query you will need to set up your own connection separate from Drupal and use that.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=drupal';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
```

Then using the custom queries will work. and you won't get the no parameters were bound error

Comment: Just a note. For the particular example in question there is no need to bind manually, and thus no dedicated connection is ever needed.